Girl gets kidnapped, rats, guy gets stabbed in eyes
I can only remember bits and pieces of this movie, and cannot find it anywhere on Google. 
From what I remember, some lady has a little daughter or daughter like figure. This lady hallucinates or dreams of tons of rats all in her daughter's room. Her daughter gets kidnapped. This man is trying to help her find her daughter. He drives her to some place and is waiting for her in the car. Someone gets in the back seat of his car, and he turns around thinking it's her, but it's some old/older lady who stabs him in the eyes with some sort of skewer or crochet needles or something similar in looks. I also remember a church and a group of rats running up the aisle and forming into the devil or something/someone evil. 

you’re probably looking for the crime horror drama movie Bless the Child (2000) by Chuck Russel with Kim Basinger and Rufus Sewell. The plot contains a kidnapped girl, a person dreams that hundreds of rats are crawling around a room and a guy’s eyes are stabbed with knitting needles …  
